# Не получается установить пакеты на python

Tags: python

пытаюсь поставить данную либу https://github.com/craigfrancis/audio-detect, выполняю команду pip3 install -r requirements.txt, в итоге полотно ошибок, не ставятся пакеты какие-то, в чем дело, кто подскажет?

```
Building wheel for numba (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [731 lines of output]
      TBB not found
      OpenMP disabled
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      got version from file C:\Users\manwi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1tkqq69u\numba_1488b10755af46fe828a5281f154206a\numba/_version.py {'version': '0.48.0', 'full': 'cc7e7c7cfa6389b54d3b5c2c95751c97eb531a96'}
      running build_py
      
   × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [24 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      C:\Python\python.exe C:\Users\manwi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1tkqq69u\llvmlite_b383071f394f483fb76b1614ec703ecd\ffi\build.py
      Trying generator 'Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64'
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\manwi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1tkqq69u\llvmlite_b383071f394f483fb76b1614ec703ecd\ffi\build.py", line 168, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\manwi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1tkqq69u\llvmlite_b383071f394f483fb76b1614ec703ecd\ffi\build.py", line 156, in main
          main_win32()
        File "C:\Users\manwi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1tkqq69u\llvmlite_b383071f394f483fb76b1614ec703ecd\ffi\build.py", line 88, in main_win32
          generator = find_win32_generator()
        File "C:\Users\manwi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1tkqq69u\llvmlite_b383071f394f483fb76b1614ec703ecd\ffi\build.py", line 76, in find_win32_generator
          try_cmake(cmake_dir, build_dir, generator)
        File "C:\Users\manwi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1tkqq69u\llvmlite_b383071f394f483fb76b1614ec703ecd\ffi\build.py", line 28, in try_cmake
          subprocess.check_call(['cmake', '-G', generator, cmake_dir])
        File "C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
          retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
        File "C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 345, in call
          with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
        File "C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child
          hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
      FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл
      error: command 'C:\\Python\\python.exe' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
```

Это не полный лог, полный вот [тут](https://wordpad.cc/QvnexhZb)

У меня Visual studio code, win10 и python 3.10.6
Ставил Microsoft C++ Build Tools, делал pip install Cmake, pip install tbb
ничего не помогает. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: надо вот на это обратить внимание `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл
      error: command 'C:\\Python\\python.exe' failed with exit code 1`

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/RIydzVI.png так у меня есть такой файл, питон установлен в папке C:\Python и там лежит файл python.exe